# How to sort MutableLiveData<List<Book>>

Tags: sorting, kotlin, viewmodel, mutablelivedata

I have MutableLiveData> in ViewModel. How can we sort it based on book name, id and so on.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where else have you looked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map` function](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#map(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20androidx.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20Y%3E)) to transform your `LiveData`.

```
val unsortedBooks: LiveData<Book> = //...
val sortedBooks: LiveData<Book> = Transformations
    .map(unsortedBooks, Function { books ->
        //sort your `books` here and return the sorted list
    })
```