# How to sort MutableLiveData ArrayList in ViewModel?

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I have an Android app (Java) that makes an api call for shows. After the shows are returned, I need to filter the show arraylist by season & then by episode. I'm currently sorting the list in my fragment because I haven't found a good solution on how to do this in my viewmodel.

This is my call in my vm:

```
public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Titles>> getTitlesListLiveData(){
    return repository.getTitlesLiveData();
}
```

And this is how I'm sorting it in my fragment:

```
    titlesViewModel.titlesListLiveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), titles -> {

        for (Titles title : titles) {
            titlesList.add(title);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            titlesList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Titles::getSeasonNumber).thenComparing(Titles::getEpisodeNumber));
        }
        binding.rvTitles.setAdapter(ShowTitlesAdapter);            
        ShowTitlesAdapter.setShowTitlesList(titlesList);

    });
    titlesViewModel.getAllTitles(ShowTag);
```

I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61242377/how-to-sort-mutablelivedatalistbook) but I don't understand how I would do it in Java or in my viewmodel. Can anyone help?

UPDATE:
I tried doing this in my ViewModel & it does not work:

```
public LiveData<List<String>> seasonsListLiveData;

seasonsListLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(titlesListLiveData, titles-> titles.sort(Comparator.comparing(Titles::getSeasonNumber).thenComparing(Titles::getEpisodeNumber));
```

The error I get: Required type:
LiveData
<List>
Provided:
LiveData

no instance(s) of type variable(s) Y exist so that void conforms to LiveData

Also tried using Transformations.map() & received the same error.

Comment: *I don't understand how I would do it in Java*... Ain't it already in Java? For sorting in view model; what is your data source, a database or a network? If first you can sort them in the database query. Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: My code is in Java, the the solution I referenced in the link above is in Kotlin. I'm using Retrofit to make my api calls. Is this sortable? Call<ArrayList<Titles>> getTitles(@Query("tags") String show_tag)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [LiveData Transformations](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata). In your case it could be something like this:

```
public LiveData<List<Titles>> getTitlesListLiveData()
{
    return Transformations.map( repository.getTitlesLiveData(), titles ->
            titles.sort(Comparator.comparing(Titles::getSeasonNumber).thenComparing(Titles::getEpisodeNumber))
    );
}
```

Also you don't have to set the adapter every time the data changes:

```
binding.rvTitles.setAdapter(ShowTitlesAdapter);
```

You can set it once, for example in the onCreate (when in Activity) or in onCreateView (when in Fragment). Then when the data changes you just call the `setShowTitlesList` to change the data in adapter

Comment: Your solution seems promising, but I'm getting an "no instance(s) of type variable(s) Y exist so that void conforms to Y" error - Required type: LiveData
<List<Titles>>, Provided: LiveData<Object>. I can't sort if I change Titles to a List.